# Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Adminpanel\Utility\StateUtility' not found

Tags: php, composer-php, typo3

I am really new to typo3 so I tried to set it up locally and configure the The official Introduction Package extension to create the first Typo3 webpage. After installing the extension via the "Extensions" page in the CMS, I configured routing links.

When I navigate to the 'base' page, I get the error `Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Adminpanel\Utility\StateUtility' not found`.

If I try to create an auto generated page via `Web/Page` and navigate to it, I get the same error.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Please install the system extension. If you are using composer, use `composer require typo3/cms-adminpanel`, otherwise just install it in the extension manager.